# Como usar o Data Table Server Side?

Tags: datatable

Estou tentando seguir esse tutorial:
https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html

Mas está dando o erro na hora que eu busco algo, ou clico na paginação:

DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: Está usando php?

Comment: Sim, inseri os dados de conexão, como pede ai nesse link, mas da esse erro.

Comment: Parece que o json não é válida, veio um espaço ou outro caracter a mais nele.

Answer (score 0):

Vou traduzir da própria documentação do DataTables, o que fala para se fazer nesta situação:

Acesse o Developer tools no Firefox:

O painel network ira mostrar todas as requisições feitas pelo Firefox para carregar a página.

Clique em XHR para filtrar as requisições XHR somente.
Dê duplo click na requisição Ajax feita pelo DataTables.
Vão aparecer detalhes desta requisição, clique na aba response para ver que dados foram retornados pelo servidor.

Uma vez tendo a resposta da requisição Ajax do servidor voce pode validar a resposta JSON
usando ferramentas como JSON Lint ou JSON Parser.

Uma vez seguido as instruções acima e descoberto qual dados o servidor retornou, e não foi um JSON, você será capaz de mudar os dados ou o programa que cria os dados para retornar um JSON válido.